# Winter bash icon doesn't appear with Chrome browser on Android phone

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2014

The winter bash icon doesn't appear on my Android phone with the Chrome browser. From the image below, you can see it isn't present.

[image]

Comment: That is probably because of slow internet connection. WB script loads after the page load. So if you have slow connection or the connection was interrupted, the script won't load. Does it appear on your computer?

Comment: @nicael It appears on my computer. I don't have a slow connection and my phone is on wifi right now.

Comment: It is not present on an iPhone either; the Winter Bash script simply doesn't run on mobile browsers even when using the full site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you know if it is designed that way or a bug?

Comment: @dustin most likely designed that way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks. I will wait to see if a mod or someone with the access to such information can offer some feedback.

Comment: @Mart Not true, I am now on SGS5 in the Chrome and winterbash is there.

Comment: @nicael all the more likely it is a browser capability filter then; most likely display size is tested. 1920x1080 is enough while my iPhone 5 has less space (1136x640).

Comment: @Mart Maybe, SGS5 has 1920x1080px display. Thats the same resoluation as on my dell monitor :D

Comment: @nicael my display is: 5.2 in (130 mm) diagonal IPS LCD 1920x1080 (424 ppi) with Gorilla Glass 2

Comment: Yep, mine is the same (gorilla glass doesn't matter there, mine probably has another version :D). But on SGS5 *everything* is supposed to work :D

Comment: @nicael I know I just copy and pasted since I am lazy. I wonder what the problem is since it works on yours and not on mine or the iPhone.

Comment: Officially they don't build things on the main site to work on mobile browsers. Anything that does work is by chance and it's *incredibly* unlikely that they will make any changes to try and support Winterbash on a mobile device.

Comment: It dosent appear in my mobile Nokia C1 Opera Mini 4.5 and also in Opera 8.0 browsers.

Comment: Thats very strange that nobody has it working. For me, works in all mine browsers - Opera, Chrome, Internet (default browser).